# Module '"@pinecone-database/pinecone"' has no exported member 'PineconeClient'.ts(2305)

Tags: pinecone

I'm trying to use `PineconeClient`, importing from "@pinecone-database/pinecone";

But I'm getting the following error:

Module '"@pinecone-database/pinecone"' has no exported member 'PineconeClient'.ts(2305)

I tried to update but it didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Please check your @pinecone-database/pinecone library version, because from v1.1.0 they removed PineconeClient.

following is the updated way of creating pincone client,

```
import { Pinecone } from '@pinecone-database/pinecone';

const pc = new Pinecone({
  apiKey: 'your_api_key',
});
```

You can refer following link for the same:

https://docs.pinecone.io/legacy/getting-started/quickstart

Please try this solution, if you still find an error let me know.